# QGIS: Legend Patch Shapes tab is missing in Style Manager

Tags: qgis, legend

I want to use legend patches, but my QGIS 3.4 Style Manager is missing a **Legend Patch Shapes** tab.

Expectations:
[image: Expected style manager]

Reality:

[image: Current style manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tab was added with QGIS 3.14 release

[feature-manage-legend-patch-shapes-through-style-manager](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html#feature-manage-legend-patch-shapes-through-style-manager)

So it's expected to not find it in earlier version. If you want to use it you need to upgrade.

As you are using a quite old version (the latest is 3.30 and latest LTR is 3.28) upgrading will give you lot of other improvement...

Comment: Ah.. so simple solution. I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it myself..